# Node server-side API configuration will not redirect the PORT to 443

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, nginx

I am trying to build a web site from scratch. Everything has been good so far, but I am trying to make my API use port `443` to make the `URL` use `https` as well, but I don't even know if it is possible to do that because I am using that port for `Nginx` on my VPS. And I have to mention that I am using Cloudflare as well.

Here is my [Server.js](https://github.com/Sadraw/quot.is/blob/main/server/server.js) Configuration which you can see on the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Sadraw/quot.is).

And Here is my `Nginx config` for my website. I tried to redirect port `5000` to `443` but it doesn't do it for me:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name quot.is www.quot.is;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name quot.is www.quot.is;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/quot_certificate.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/quot_private_key.key;

    root /var/www/quot.is/client/build;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name api.quot.is;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name api.quot.is;

    # Remove these SSL-related lines, as SSL is handled by Cloudflare
    # ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/quot_certificate.pem;
    # ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/quot_private_key.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just an update. I want the domain for the api be like: ```api.quot.is``` instead of ```api.quot.is:5000``` and use https.